# Get associated ActiveRecord::Relation from complex query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following AR models:

```ruby
class Checkin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :checkins
end
```

Let's say I have a complex query on checkins and users, for example, `Checkin.nearby.today` and `User.friends_of(john)`. Is there a straightforward way I can derive an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Users`? The end result would be friends of John who have checked in nearby today.

I would like the end result to be an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up side-stepping ActiveRecord but your answer was correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
users = User.friends_of(john)
users = users.joins(:checkins).where(checkins: { checkin_date: Date.today })
users = users.where( # your logic to determine the nearby )
```

As you can see, there is the logic about the nearby scope missing.

In a custom method:

```
def self.friends_checked_nearby_at_date(friend, nearby = true, date = Date.today)
  users = User.friends_of(friend)
  users = users.joins(:checkins).where(checkins: { checkin_date: date })
  users = users.where( # your logic for the nearby scope ) if nearby.present?

  return users
end

# usage:
User.friends_checked_nearby_at_date( User.first )
# or 
User.friends_checked_nearby_at_date( User.first, true, Date.today-1.week )
# or
User.friends_checked_nearby_at_date( User.first, false )
# etc.
```